# Best approach for un-installing SharePoint Designer 2013 from my windows server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, configuration, installation, windows-server

I have two SharePoint farms; Live & Test. both have the following software specification.

1. SharePoint enterprise server 2013, with SP1.
2. installed inside windows server 2008 R2.

Now when I built our Live & Test servers, I had installed SharePoint Designer 2013, but lately I have read many articles which mentioned that it is recommended not not install any office or other application other than SharePoint inside SharePoint servers. So now I am planning to uninstall SharePoint Designer. Now on our Test server, I followed these steps:

1. Control Panel.
2. Uninstall a program.
3. select SharePoint Designer 2013.
4. click on remove.

SP Designer got uninstalled correctly but not sure if this is the recommended way to uninstall SP designer. Now I am planning to uninstall SP designer on live server and could uninstalling SP designer cause any problem to SharePoint ?

Since both SharePoint service 2013 & SharePoint Designer 2013 are within the office suite, they might share some patches, updates and .dll files. So my concern if I uninstall SharePoint Designer inside the SharePoint server could this remove .dll or patches which is related to SharePoint or will uninstalling SharePoint Designer not affect SharePoint and will not conflict with the .dlls, patches related to SharePoint??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling from Control Panel is the recommended way.

This will ensure all files and registry entries get removed. Also I don't this this will affect in any way. I have installed and uninstalled SPD from various environments and never faced any issues.

Comment: i was afraid that if i remove SPD it might affect the farm build number for sharepoint .... now on Test it did not ,, but i just wanted to make sure there is not any risk ..

Comment: No farm build number is entirely depends on the update packages and configuration wizard.. You can try this in TEST if you are concerned.. I hope TEST and PRD are having same version numbers

Comment: yes Test and PRD do have the same build number and are always patched in the same way... what i was afraid of is that un-installing SP Desinger might remove some patches which is related to office,, where these patches could affect SP farm build number when they got installed ...now on Test i check the farm build number before and after SPD un-install and they are the same... but i did not run the product configuration wizard ...

Comment: even if you run product configuration wizard it will not affect anything unless you installed some SharePoint updates..

Comment: my point is since both sharepoint & sharepoint designer are both within the office suite,, and they might share some patches and updates and .dll files.. so my concern if i un-install sharepoint designer could this remove dll or patches which is related to sharepoint ???

Comment: Nope that is not the case.. That's reason we are using the uninstalled which take care of removing what it installed and not remove any shared dlls

Comment: and does this apply to any patches ... i mean could un-installing SPD cause a patch to be removed,, where this patch is related to sharepoint,, or this is not valid also ?